Does Mahayana Buddhism hold that the Buddha derived his Philosophy from Vedanta?
Professor VV Gokhale in a paper titled "The Vedanta-Philosophy described by Bhavya in his Madhyamakahrdaya" (Indo-Iranian Journal, Vol. 2, No. 3, 1958) discusses a work named mAdhyamakahridaya by Bhavya, a sixth century mAdhyamaka buddhist. In the discussion, He refers to a situation where the mahAyAna school is criticised as being similar to vedAnta in the said work. In reply, Apparently Bhavya  says that whatever is good in the upaniShads has also been taught by the Buddha. To cite-

In one of the chapters of the Madhyamakahridaya dealing with the
hInayAna objections to mahAyAna, the hInayAna-buddhist criticises the
mahAyAna buddhist saying;-
न बुद्धोक्तिर्महायानं सूत्रान्तादावसंग्रहात् | मार्गान्तरोपदेषात् वा
यथा वेदान्तदर्शनम् ||
The mAhAyAna teaching was not spoken of by the Buddha, either because
it is not included in the sUtrAntas, or because like the vedAnta
darshana, it teaches heretic paths to salvation.
To this attack, the mahAyAnist replies -
वेदान्ते च हि यत् सूक्तम् तत् सर्वं बुद्धभाषितम् | दृष्टान्तन्यूनता
तस्मात् संदिग्धं वा परीक्ष्यताम् ||
Whatever is well said in the vedAnta (upaniShads) has been taught by
the Buddha. The various examples cited by the hInayAna are faulty and
what is doubtful must be examined.

Questions-

Is that a unanimous view among the Mahayana Buddhists that Buddha's teachings were inspired from vedanta?

How would adherents from other schools of buddhism view the statements of Bhavya?



Hi. Please link your source document. Thanks

@DhammaDhatu I was given the following source from a vedanta forum. (https://www.jstor.org/stable/24648516)

I read/browsed this: https://www.jainfoundation.in/JAINLIBRARY/books/vedanta_philosophy_described_by_bhavya_in_his_madhyamaka_hrdaya_269378_hr6.pdf

Yes, the statements I cited in the question can be seen on the pages numbered 179 and 180 in the document

Please see this answer. All schools of Vedanta were established only centuries after the founding of Mahayana Buddhist schools. So, it's only logical that Vedanta borrowed from Mahayana.

My browsing came to find the Mahayana Buddhist Bhavya said: "what is well-spoken in the Vedanta is all taught by the Buddha". However, Bhavya did not actually specify or list what is well-spoken in the Vedanta. Obviously Bhavya did not agree with all of the doctrine of the Vedanta but instead said only (unspecified) parts of the Vedanta conform with the Buddha. For example, the Vedanta refers to concepts taught by the Buddha such as the "unborn", the "undying", "transcends the world", "luminousness", "surpasses all bondage", "immunity from birth & death", "tranquility", etc.
As for the Hinayana objections mentioned in the essay, these appear very superficial, namely, referring to the mutual conduct of various rituals by the Vedantists & Mahayanists and appearing to assert both schools avoiding moral teachings about non-killing, non-robbing, etc.
The above said, the quotes from T in the article of the Vedanta view show Mahayana concepts that do not match Pali Sutta, such as "sunyata" meaning "unsubstantial, unreal" etc. In Pali Sutta, "sunnata" simply means "void of self" (SN 35.85). Thus, even today, Mahayana and Theravada are always debating this matter, as done often on this & other chatsites.

In essence, this T text is very insightful because it demonstrates how non-Pali Sutta concepts of Mahayana allowed the Vedanta to debunk the Mahayana. Thus we can observe here how Hinduism came to debunk Buddhism due to either the emphasis or otherwise prominence of Mahayana Buddhism in central/northern India.
For example, all the assertions by the Vedanta about "the soul" and how there can be no liberation without a "soul' is easy answered/addressed by replying the Pali Suttas actually say it is the "citta/ceto" that is liberated (however the Pali Suttas also say this citta is not permanent & not eternal). For example, the Pali Suttas say:

“This mind, mendicants, is radiant.
“Pabhassaramidaṁ, bhikkhave, cittaṁ.
But it’s corrupted by passing corruptions.”
Tañca kho āgantukehi upakkilesehi upakkiliṭṭhan”ti.
“This mind, mendicants, is radiant.
“Pabhassaramidaṁ, bhikkhave, cittaṁ.
And it is freed from passing corruptions.”
Tañca kho āgantukehi upakkilesehi vippamuttan”ti.
AN 1.49-50


The goal, heartwood, and final end of the spiritual life is the
unshakable freedom of heart.
Yā ca kho ayaṁ, bhikkhave, akuppā cetovimutti— etadatthamidaṁ,
bhikkhave, brahmacariyaṁ, etaṁ sāraṁ etaṁ pariyosānan
MN 29

So, yes, the Mahayana, due to their inadequate & superstitious doctrine of nothingness, allows another superstitious doctrine of eternalism to ridicule it. This is similar to the debates that occurred in Ceylon (Sri Lanka) between the Theravada Buddhists and the colonizer Christians; where each side of the debate accused each other of superstition. Its the ridiculous situation where one side superstitiously believes in God or The Soul and the other side superstitiously believes in reincarnation &/or rebirth. Similarly, the Mahayana held the extreme superstitious view that there is nothing liberated and the Vedantists held the extreme superstitious view that an Eternal Soul is required for liberation.
In summary, the Pali Suttas do not contain any of the Mahayana & Abhidhamma doctrines the Vedantists are debating, namely:

Sunyata as unsubstantiality.

Unrealness.

Momentariness.

No 'thing' is liberated.


These historical texts again show how Buddhism caused its own demise in India.

Nvm, My investigation in search of the verse cited in the paper led me to looking into the original work:- https://archive.org/details/madhyamikamadhyamakahrduyaofbhavyalindterchr.adyarlibrary_793_M/page/n37/mode/2up?view=theater
From the above summary of Madhyamaka hrdaya, Turns out Bhavya too holds the view that vedanta borrowed from buddhism which is why the absolute in vedanta is occasionally understood the same way as in madhyamika.
